# What is extension-method in http request per RFC

Tags: http

I was reading the http request RFC (just for fun) and I noticed this section has an extension-method = token...

```
Method         = "OPTIONS"                ; Section 9.2
                  | "GET"                    ; Section 9.3
                  | "HEAD"                   ; Section 9.4
                  | "POST"                   ; Section 9.5
                  | "PUT"                    ; Section 9.6
                  | "DELETE"                 ; Section 9.7
                  | "TRACE"                  ; Section 9.8
                  | "CONNECT"                ; Section 9.9
                  | extension-method
   extension-method = token
```

What is this 'token' or 'extension-method'.  Does that mean method can literally just be anything?  I don't see where token is defined.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Maybe if you told us which rfc exactly you mean. But the real answer: go down further, and search for the definition of "token"

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html and token was not defined as far as I could see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are looking at a very outdated document. The relevant RFCs are 7230, 7231 etc.

And yes, method can be any string conforming to the "token" ABNF, defined in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#rule.token.separators